# Redirect a form submit with ajax

Tags: html, ajax

I want to send form responses to a Google sheet and then redirect the user to a thank you page. The Google script redirects the user directly to a report page. I want to drop the google redirect and place mine.

Form:

```
<form method="post" id="formID" action="gscript">
...
</form>
```

Script:

```
<script>
   $(document).on('submit', '.formID', function(e) {
     $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(html) {
        alert('ok');
        window.location("Thanks page link");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();

});
</script>
```

Comment: shouldn't `.formID` be `#formID` ?

Comment: Right, it should x)

Comment: Still not working. :(

Comment: beside the typo of `#formID` try placing this line `e.preventDefault();` on top of the function

Comment: Both changed but still doing the wrong redirect

Answer (score 0):

Add a .success() callback function to be called when the request finished, well, successfully. In the function, redirect the user to your desired *thank you* page.

Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    ...
    success: function(result) {
        // result unused, drop it if you want :)
        window.location.replace('url_to_your_thank_you_page');
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow. I copied his code, and there was no success function. Am I blind or did SO troll me?

Comment: too much coffee and time in front of the screen, happens to us all :)

Comment: I don't even drink coffee x) Guess I'm blind. Retiring my answer. Your initial call was right. (Okay deleting doesn't work either. I need sleep....)

Answer (score 0):

First of all change this `$(document).on('submit', '.formID', function(e) {` to this `$(document).on('submit', '#formID', function(e) {`.
Now try placing this line `e.preventDefault();` on top, before the `ajax` call:

```
$('#formID').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(html) {
            alert('ok');
            window.location("Thanks page link");
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**
following your comment, i'm not familiar with gscript's API but maybe consider placing a `button` that will invoke a function of yours then problematically do `$('#myForm').submit()`

Comment: i've update my answer try `$('#formID').submit`. whats not working do you get an error?

Comment: When you use a google script as action the submit button send you to a report page. It's like the script doesn't matter and still go in, without errors.

Comment: @David i've updated my answer following your comment